# Use promise from `stdout` from child_process.exec

Tags: node.js, terminal, callback, promise, command-line-interface

I am using `('child_process').exec;` by running `bash` command that returns some `output` and  I am waiting for special word. How I can rewrite my example with promises?

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').exec;

const doEcho = spawn('echo "hello world"');
doEcho.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.includes('world')) {
        // run some other commands
    }
});
```

Comment: read this until it clicks: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite it with promises?

Comment: @robertklep I have a chain of commands that I want to run. I don't want to have _callback hell_  and also I want start new data base (rethinkdb) . And if starting of new db will fail I want to catch it, and even if it failing ourput is `stdout` nor `stderr`. Or srting takes more time than usual. With promises (async/await) it easier for me to handle it.

Comment: Promises represent a single (future) value, whereas `doEcho.stdout` is a continuous stream. A promise would only make sense here if the condition `data.includes('world')` would only be true (at most) once. Is that the case? Or do "some other commands" need to be run _each time_ the condition is true?

Comment: @robertklep yes, I need to catch it once and then run next command

Comment: you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/callback-promise